# List initialization of const and array structure fields

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Just recently started C++ programming for micro-controllers, and I've ran into situations* where it would be convenient to have a non-static const field on a struct that is always guaranteed to have a fixed value (same for every instance of the sturct, ever).

Given a struct

```
struct S {
    const uint8_t c; // Should always be 42
    char v;
    uint32_t arr[4];
}
```

I'd like `c` to be a constant value, and the same constant value every time. I would love to be able to use the convenience of brace initializer lists, for setting v and the members of arr like

`S some_var = {'v', { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };`

Since I'd like `c` to be a constant, I'm under the impression that I have to use an initializer list for setting `c`, such as `S() : c(42) {}`, which works just fine, as long as I don't try to also initialize `arr`, in which case I'm lost on how the list should look like. Is this doable using C++11? (Also interested in an answer if this is not doable in C++11, but in some newer standard.)

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct S {
    const uint8_t c; // Should always be 42 on every instance
                     // of the struct due to hardware shenanigance
                     // (i.e. this struct is the representation of a register value)
    char v;
    uint32_t arr[4];

    // This allows using "S s1;"
    S() : c(42), v('a'), arr{} {}

    // This allows using "S s2 = { 'v', 0, 1, 2, 3 };" works but it's clumsy:
    S(uint32_t v, uint32_t arr0, uint32_t arr1, uint32_t arr2, uint32_t arr3) :
        c(42), v(v), arr{ arr0, arr1, arr2, arr3 } {}

    // I would like to do something along the lines of "S s2 = { 'v', { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };":
    // S(uint32_t v, uint32_t arr[4] /*?*/) :
    //     c(42), v(v), arr{/*?*/} {}

};

// Main just for the sake of completeness
int main() {
    // Works just fine
    S s1;
    printf("s1.c = %u\n", s1.c); // 42
    printf("s1.v = '%c'\n", s1.v); // a
    printf("s1.arr[3] = %u\n", s1.arr[3]); // 0

    // Initialiation like this works with the line:12 signature:
    S s2 = { 'v', 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    // I'd like to initialize like this:
    // S s2 = { 'v', { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };

    printf("s2.c = %u\n", s2.c); // 42
    printf("s2.v = '%c'\n", s2.v); // v
    printf("s2.arr[3] = %u\n", s2.arr[3]); // 3
    return 0;
}
```

---

*Context on why I'd want to do this: This might seem like a weird thing to want, since if the value is always the same, why bother storing it? Well imagine that the struct in question is a bitfield which corresponds to the register of an IC with which the micro-controller communicates. These registers sometimes have "reserved" fields, and the datasheet specifies what value you **must** write into these fields. From a programmer's point of view, it would be convenient if I never had to deal with setting said bits manually.

Comment: If all instances will have the same value, sounds like you need a static variables.  Not only will that save space since all objects will share a single variable, it also allows you to keep your aggregate initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver Please read the footnote at the end of the question. Imagine you want to pass a bitfield to some hardware of the form `1111000xxxxxxxxx` where the `11110000` is always the same/required and the `xxxxxxxx` is the data you want to communicate.

Comment: Note: It's likely that the compiler inserts padding between `v` and `arr`, which will probably mess up the communication with the microcontroller. Most compilers allow you to avoid the padding (by something like `#pragma pack`) but that's not really portable.

Comment: Yes, @MaxLanghof is correct, I need the value to be physically present in memory. As far as I understand a static const does not satisfy this. Any tips on how to reword the question so that this is more clear?

I'm aware of the padding issue, I just wanted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 gives you [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which is like a raw array, but comes with none of the "negatives" (array decay, can't copy).  Using that you can get exactly what you want like

```
struct S {
    const uint8_t c = 42;
    char v = 'a';
    std::array<uint32_t, 4> arr{};

    // This allows using "S s1;"
    S() {}

    S(uint32_t v, std::array<uint32_t, 4> arr) : v(v), arr{arr} {}
};

// Main just for the sake of completeness
int main() {
    // Works just fine
    S s1;
    printf("s1.c = %u\n", s1.c); // 42
    printf("s1.v = '%c'\n", s1.v); // a
    printf("s1.arr[3] = %u\n", s1.arr[3]); // 0

    S s2 = { 'v', { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };

    printf("s2.c = %u\n", s2.c); // 42
    printf("s2.v = '%c'\n", s2.v); // v
    printf("s2.arr[3] = %u\n", s2.arr[3]); // 3
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
s1.c = 42
s1.v = 'a'
s1.arr[3] = 0
s2.c = 42
s2.v = 'v'
s2.arr[3] = 3
```

---

If you absoluytley have to have a raw array in `S` then your other option is to use a `std::initializer_list` in the constructor.  That would look like

```
struct S {
    const uint8_t c = 42;
    char v = 'a';
    uint32_t arr[4]{};

    // This allows using "S s1;"
    S() {}

    S(uint32_t v, std::initializer_list<uint32_t> data) : v(v)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (auto e : data)
            arr[i++] = e;
    }
};

// Main just for the sake of completeness
int main() {
    // Works just fine
    S s1;
    printf("s1.c = %u\n", s1.c); // 42
    printf("s1.v = '%c'\n", s1.v); // a
    printf("s1.arr[3] = %u\n", s1.arr[3]); // 0

    S s2 = { 'v', { 0, 1, 2, 3 } };

    printf("s2.c = %u\n", s2.c); // 42
    printf("s2.v = '%c'\n", s2.v); // v
    printf("s2.arr[3] = %u\n", s2.arr[3]); // 3
    return 0;
}
```

And you get the same results as the code using `std::array`.

Comment: It's not often that you see uniform initialization pulling through like this :D

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'd say it works about 75% of the time for me.  Really the main issue is legacy containers.  When you start from fresh you can build a better overload set for your constructors.

Comment: In my head I was looking for the std::initializer_list solution, but the std::array one seems so obvious, I feel bad for not even trying it.